# LinkedList Stack Implementation

Tags: java, beginner, linked-list, stack

I'm new to the programming and I want to ask a question about my linkedlist stack implementation if it's correct and if it meets the requirements of the linkedlist stack implementation. If there is any suggestion I'm glad to hear...

```
public class DynamicStack {
  private class Node {
     private Object item;
     private Node next;

     Node(Object item){
      this.item = item;
      this.next = null;
     }

     Node(Object item, Node nextNode){
      this.item = item;
      this.next  = nextNode;
     }
  }

 private int count;
 private Node top;

 public DynamicStack() {
   this.top = null;
   this.count = 0;
 }



 public void push(Object item) {
   if(top == null) {
      top = new Node(item);
   }else {
      Node newNode = new Node(item,top);
      top = newNode;
   }
   count++;
 }

 public Object peek() {
   if(top == null) {
      throw new NoSuchElementException("Underflow Exception");
   }else {
      return top.item;
   }
 }
 public Object pop() {
   Node currentNode = top;
   if(top == null) {
      throw new NoSuchElementException("Underflow Exception");
   }else {
      Node nextNode = top.next;
      top = null;
      top = nextNode;
   }
   count--;
   return currentNode.item;
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

This looks to me like it will work as intended. I have a few suggestions for improvement though:

- You keep the `count` variable up to date but never use it's value for anything. You can either remove it or provide a `size()` method.
- You might change your `push()` method to

> ```
> public void push(Object item){
>    top = new Node(item, top);
>    count++;
> }
> ```

If `top` is `null`, you set `node.next` to `null` in the Node constructor anyways.
 - If you do this, you can subsequently delete the Node(Item) constructor

- I personally would make the `item` and `next` member variables in Node `final` to prevent accidental mutations
- (Instead of accepting `Object` as your items you might want to introduce [Generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/intro.html) into your class. But this is an advanced topic and is maybe too hard for you as a beginner)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Yes there were two more methods for size() and clear() ,but i just didn't added them to the post. About to push() method your right, thanks. Also i saw few Generics implementations, but they are really like you say for an advanced and i was trying to implement a basic structure to learn how the stack works and to use it in the future. Also i'm sorry, because i can't +rep your comment, it was really useful - because of my reputation. Thanks again .

Answer (score 2):

One thing that you could try is moving the null-check for `peek` and `pop` to its own method.
In this way you can eliminate the if/else blocks and reduce indentation which is better for reading. Also the name gives you a quick indication what is going to happen on the error without the need to analyse the whole statement in the if.
For this code it's a very small improvement, but if the code blocks get larger, it's rather significant.

```
public Object peek() {
    breakIfTopisNull();

    return top.item;
}

public Object pop() {
    Node currentNode = top;

    breakIfTopIsNull()

    Node nextNode = top.next;
    top = null;
    top = nextNode;

    count--;
    return currentNode.item;
}

private void breakIfTopIsNull() {
    if(top == null) 
        throw new NoSuchElementException("Underflow Exception");
}
```

Comment: Method names in Java start with a lowercase letter. We also put the curly brace on the same line, not a newline.

Comment: Updated, waiting for it to be reviewed.